# Nginx server_name 52.com - How to use numerical domain names?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Maybe I'm going crazy, but I can't get a numerical domain to load anything. It just ignores server_name and loads the first site.

server_name     52.com;

Comment: You can try putting it inside double quotes. Are you sure there is no server block marked as default ?

Comment: That `server_name` will not match `www.52.com` - and the site redirects to that name.

Comment: tried using quotes, still loads 1st valid conf

Comment: @RichardSmith how can it not match and match at the same time. It should match and should load, like any other conf. What am I missing here?

Comment: I've done 500+ server confs in the past, i just dont get this, 2 days later. There has to be something off with the fact the domain is https://52.com

Comment: That domain is not working today, it currently has no A record at GoDaddy - when I tested it yesterday, it seemed to redirect to `www.52.com` (don't know why), but `www.52.com` will not match `server_name 52.com;`.

Comment: It has no A record because it is simply an example, this is a null point.
www redirects to non-www
but again, it simply does not match server_name
https://pastebin.com/7PVN1Rm6